# Issues with Wordpress database from localhost1 to localhost2

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Seen some other questions regarding this but not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is what I've done:

1. downloaded and unzipped a fresh install of wordpress to /Sites/wordpress
2. Started MAMP and set document root to above
3. Opened up phpmyadmin and created a new database named the same as the database I want to import.  (I figured I did not need to change the url's in the older database because they will be the same on my computer?  'localhost/mysite')
4. Imported localhost1 database to newly created database
5. I know that user and password created are root, but I created an additional user and password to mimic what was in the wp-config of the original site (localhost1).   I also changed localhost2's wp-config DB name, user, password to match that of localhost1 so that they are the same.

From this point I try and go to http://localhost:8888 or localhost/mysite but I basically get a 'This webpage is not available' screen as if I'm not online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with variants serialized in the database even if the URL paths stay the same. Try taking the localhost1 database and migrating to localhost2 after using a serialization tool like [this](http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/).

I realize you are not changing URL paths, however I've read that tables are all serialized so it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that out and same result.  I almost feel like I'm missing something.  I'll keep tinkering away. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my opinion is not in the database, because WP will tell you  if it is.

Problem must be in your local server configuration. In Windows I made different folder for different projects and access them like `localhost/project1`, `localhost/project2` etc.

I don't know how are things in Mac, but must be the same. So try to start a fresh copy of WP in your new localhost, and then import database from first project.

When WP first starts creates `.htaccess` file with `modrewrite`, so you can also check current `.htaccess` file and rules there.

Comment: Thanks.  Well, the reason I don't think its my local server config is because I can get a fresh install of wordpress running accordingly.  Its the moment after I import the database from the first project that suddenly nothing works.

Comment: So then, let's say I start new again, and create a new database locally with the default username and password ('root' for both).  The database I am importing seems to have the same URL scheme as mine (localhost/mysite) but different username/password.  My database user/pw stays the same correct?  As I am not importing the permissions rather just the content of the database?

Comment: I don't think that username/password is the problem, because they will need only if you try to login in admin

Comment: Let's do some things to be sure that everything is right. Install a fresh copy of WP, load site, then login to admin. If is ok, open database and check in `wp_options` table value for the key `'siteurl'`. Then check this value in your old DB, to see if they are the same. In my test site in wp_temp folder this value is `http://localhost/wp_temp`. Then check your `.htaccess` file for the rewrite rules, which WP has created. In my test site they are `RewriteBase /wp_temp/`, `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`, `RewriteRule . /wp_temp/index.php [L]`.You must be sure for this rules.